# How can I show the error message in the modal popup in my web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need some advise on how to get the error message, in this case the ping response, to show up in the modal popup window.

So basically what happens now is that when a device is offline a modal popups with header "Device Offline!".  Then in the body of the modal it has some text specified in the modal itself:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <h4 class="modal-title">Device Offline!</h4>
           </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This then gets displayed for 3 seconds then closes using the following:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    function openModal() {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        }, 3000);
    }
</script>
```

To call the modal popup i use:

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
```

So when the device goes offline I need to replace the `<p>Some text in the modal.</p>` with the error message (in this case, `Destination host unreachable`)

This is the code i use for that:

```
  string destIP = GridView3.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Ping p = new Ping();
                        PingReply reply;
                        reply = p.Send(destIP);

                        if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        {
                            if (reply.RoundtripTime > 50)
                            {
                                Image2.ImageUrl = "../Images/yellow.png";
                                serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image2);
                                Image2.ToolTip = Convert.ToString("RoundTripTime: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms");
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                Image3.ImageUrl = "../Images/green.png";
                                serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image3);
                                Image3.ToolTip = Convert.ToString("RoundTripTime: " + reply.RoundtripTime + "ms");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Image4.ImageUrl = "../Images/red.png";
                            serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image4);
                            Image4.ToolTip = reply.Status.ToString();
                            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (PingException err)
                    {
                        Image4.ImageUrl = "../Images/red.png";
                        serverPanel.Controls.Add(Image4);
                        Image4.ToolTip = err.Message.ToString();
                    }
                }
```

So when the modal pops up it need to display the header and then in the body the actual error message.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block call the modal and pass in the error message.

```
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal(" + err.Message.ToString() + ");", true);
```

Then pass in the message to your js

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function openModal(message) {
$('#pid').value = message;
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
 
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }, 3000);
}
</script>

<p id=pid>Some text in the modal.</p>
```